# Hiding the Flash object for ZeroClipboard link?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality of the "copy to clipboard" link on Github: [image: Github copy link]

Github seems to be able to make it so that clicking the button doesn't take you "in" to Flash. When I implemented it, it requires an extra click out to get back to the browser.

Also wondering how Github makes it so that when right-clicking the button, it shows a regular HTML button instead of a Flash pop-up option.

[image: Flash right-click menu]

Does anyone know how Github makes it appear so that the ZeroClipboard object doesn't behave like a Flash object?